# How to restrict HATEOAS navigation links based on WebAPI permissions?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core-webapi, hateoas

I'm toying with the idea of adding `HATEOAS` type links to the data being returned from my `WebAPI` routes that will provide clues to the client as to what actions are available on any given piece of data.

So, I might have something like:

```json
clients: {
  data: [
    {data: {id: 1, name: "Client One", age: 1}, 
     _links: {
       self: {href: ".../api/clients/1}, method: "get"}
       edit: {href: ".../api/clients/1}, method: "put"}
       delete: {href: ".../api/clients/1}, method: "delete"}
     }
    }
  ],
  _links: {
    self: {href: ".../api/clients", method: "get"},
    add: {href: ".../api/clients", method: "post"}
  }
}
```

I've seen a number of posts that talk about how to include the links so that part isn't an issue.

**The Problem**

Part of the idea behind `HATEOAS` is to make your data self-defining / self-navigating.  So, what I'd like to see is to have my `_links` only include those that are available to the user based on his/her permissions.  IOW, if the user was allowed to `Edit` a client but not `Delete` the client, then the `_links` should include the edit but not the delete.

The problem then is that in generating the links, I would actually need to evaluate the `Authorization Policy` of the Action/Route in order to determine if the link should be included.

So given something like this (this is intended as a talking point -- not actual code):

```cs
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
[APIController]
[Authorize(Policy="HR")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase {

   [HttpGet]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetClients() { 
       var results = new List<dynamic>();
       var list = context.Clients.Select(u => new BasicClient(u.Id, u.Name))
          .ToList();

       foreach(var client in list){
         //If user has access to GetClient Action
         if(??) { 
           client._links.Self.Href = Url.Action("GetClient", new {id = client.Id});
         }

         //If user has access to DeleteClient Action
         if(??) {
           client._links.Delete.Href = Url.Action("DeleteClient", new {id = client.Id});
        }
        ...
   }

   [HttpGet("{id}", Name="GetClient")]
   [Authorize(Policy="ViewClient")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetClient(int id){ ... }

   [HttpDelete("{id}", Name="DeleteClient")]
   [Authorize(Policy="DeleteClient")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteClient(int id) { ... }
```

A user would need the permissions necessary to satisfy both the `HR` and `ViewClients` policies in order to get the `self` link and additionally the `DeleteClients` policy to get the `delete` link.

Is this possible?  Am I thinking about this wrong?  Is there a better way?

**Clarification**

While it is possible to use the `AuthorizationService` to check a specific Policy, what I'm trying to do is avoid the use of hard-coded policies.  The Policies have already been defined on the `Controller` and `Actions` that I'm trying to access.  I want to know if there is a way to validate a user against an `Action` (and let the framework sort out what Policy needs to be applied).

So, in the same way that `Url.Action("GetClient",...)` takes the name of an `Action` and builds the correct link based on the defined routes, I want something like `AuthService.AuthorizeAction("GetClient", User)` that will figure out what permissions are necessary and if the User has those permissions.

Was hoping that .NetCore has something built in that does that.  If not, I suppose I could use reflection and the `IAuthorizationService` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[`IAuthorizationService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.iauthorizationservice?view=aspnetcore-3.0) is the service you're looking for. Here is a code snippet:

```cs
var result = await authorization.AuthorizeAsync(User, "IsLucky");
IsLucky = result.Succeeded;
```

Credit: https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2019/05/30/evaluating-asp-net-core-authorization-policies.aspx

Comment: I probably didn't explain clearly enough.  What I'm trying to do is test the policy of each route based on what is defined on the route -- not by hard-coding.  IOW, in my example, the `DeleteClient` route has the `DeleteClient` Policy defined.  I want to somehow check that the user has rights to the `DeleteClient` route without hardcoding the `DeleteClient` policy.  If the Policy changes down the road, I don't want to have to search my code for hard-coded checks on that Policy.

Comment: @RHarris as you've explained in the edit, reflection seems like the way to go if you want to automate it. You could also use constants, that way you don't need to change it everywhere.